# Hive query for a specific scenario

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a scenario for which I wanted to write a Hive query. The scenario is here:

The data is like below:

[image]

Now, the output I am expecting is:

[image]

Null/empty values to be ignored.

Essentially, I want the sum of values in columns col1, col2, col3 and col4 and grouped the values. The 'id' column is irrelevant here, but provided for illustration.

Any helping in writing a HiveQL query for this scenario would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select val, count(1)
from test_table lateral view explode(array(col1,col2,col3,col4)) t as val
where val is not null
group by val
```

explain:

`test_table` is your table name.
If you have more columns than 4, put them in the `array` function.

First I collect all of your columns into an array.And then use the `lateral view explode(array)` to make the array items in one column.At last group by this column and make the count.

Comment: any idea what is the best way to write the same query in Impala?  Impala does not support LATERAL VIEW. An immediate and crude method that comes to my mind is to consider each column separately and group it, and then UNION it to get the answer. Is there a better way that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this in HIVE

```
select e.single_col,count(e.single_col) from (
select stack(4,col1,col2,col3,col4) as single_col from challenge ) e
where e.single_col != ''
group by e.single_col;
```

challenge is the table used here.
The data is loaded into the table as a text format delimited with commas

```
1,A,B,,D
2,B,C,D,
3,,D,C,
4,,A,A,
```